# How to automatically wrap text after N characters?

Tags: flutter

I'm displaying items with ListView.builder like this

[image]

As you can see, if really long names like "Speedy Motor Services 1234567890" is used, then the text beside it will be severely squeezed.

Code:

```
return ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, position) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 6.0),
                  child: FittedBox(
                    fit:BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    child: Text(_displayedList[position].name,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)), 
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12.0, 6.0, 12.0, 12.0),
                  child: Text(_displayedList[position].location,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12.0, 6.0, 12.0, 12.0),
                  child: Text(_displayedList[position].distance.toString()+" KM",                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child:Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  //Expanded(),
                  Text(_displayedList[position].services.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey), softWrap: true,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: Icon(Icons.phone, size: 20, color: Colors.green[700],),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Divider(
        height: 2.0,
        color: Colors.grey,
      )
    ],
  );
},
itemCount: _displayedList.length);
},))]),)
```

I tried using FittedBox, it didn't perform like I expect.
Is there any way to, say wrap the text each 15 characters?

What I want is something like this:

[image]

Comment: wrap ? with what ??

Comment: what the result you are seeking to ? please put it in the comment or edit your question by it

Comment: 15 character of you name string?

Comment: @MohamedGaber I just added another picture which hopefully clarifies my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to wrap the content with the `expanded` and use `flex`

Here is the code snnipet inside the `column`

```
Expanded(
            flex : 2,
            child :Row(
                       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 6.0),
              child: FittedBox(
                fit:BoxFit.fitWidth,
                child: Text(_displayedList[position].name,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)), 
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12.0, 6.0, 12.0, 12.0),
              child: Text(_displayedList[position].location,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12.0, 6.0, 12.0, 12.0),
              child: Text(_displayedList[position].distance.toString()+" KM",                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
              ),
            ),
          ],
                 ),
           ),Expanded(
               flex :1,
              child:Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  //Expanded(),
                  Text(_displayedList[position].services.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey), softWrap: true,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: Icon(Icons.phone, size: 20, color: Colors.green[700],),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Now you need to just adjust the `flex` to the UI requirement.

Comment: Ah I got it. Replaced the Column with Expanded. Now I have 2 Expandeds. Set the 1st flex 3, and the 2nd flex 2. It works OK :)